# accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused only gets called with VoiceOver enabled

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, keyboard, accessibility

**Background**

- I have a UICollectionViewCell, where I override `accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused` method.
- I also override `canBecomeFocused` to always return `true`.
- The App allows `Accessibility`->`Full Keyboard Access` (allowing the user to use the app with just Keyboard). `isAccessibilityElement` is also set to `true`

**Problem**
I have two scenarios

1. When both Keyboard access and VoiceOver are enabled
   In this case `accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused` gets called as expected.
2. When both Keyboard access is enabled but VoiceOver is disabled
   In this case `accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused` isn't getting called.

Comment: that is expected. The focus is tied to voice over, without it, none of the accessibility apis work.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri thanks for the comment. Do you know of a way to get a callback when an element gets focused via keyboard without VoiceOver?

Comment: maybe im wrong, with keyboard control, you can only control the app. However there is no such things as focused by keyboard. For iOS, focus only works with voice over enabled. You might want to look at existing keyboard apis that gives callbacks on keyboard actions. I never worked on such feature other than voice over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on Developer apple forums, and one of the apple engineers confirm that indeed this API only works with VoiceOver.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/745602?login=true&page=1#778932022

The engineer highlighted the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifocussystem API for Keyboard related focus, where I found and used `didUpdateNotification` Notification for my usecase. This notification triggered as expected when I changed focus only using KeyboardAccess